# MySQL query pattern matching

Tags: mysql, .net

First of all, here is a simplified version of the table I'm working on:

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║  ID   ║ FIRSTNAME ║ LASTNAME ║ COMPANYID ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 12345 ║ Bob       ║ Smith    ║         3 ║
║ 13826 ║ Bob       ║ Smith.Mr ║         3 ║
║ 16326 ║ Bob       ║ Smith Mr ║         3 ║
║ 16382 ║ Dr.Bob    ║ Smith    ║         3 ║
║ 18372 ║ Kim       ║ Johnson  ║         3 ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Given only the id 12345 I am supposed to be able to get all records based on the name I get from 12345 and his companyID, so basically everything from Bob Smith of Company 3.

I'm not sure how to approach this query, I need a way to strip any titles, spaces or dots from his first and last name. I'm assuming I would concatinate first name with last name and run a function to remove what I have to:

Mr, Dr, Jr, Sr, etc...

And end up with bobsmith. I will need to do this to the name associated with id 12345 AND also within the `WHERE` clause, right? This would be to compare the names.

I'm trying to make this query as quick and efficient as possible, should I be using a sub `SELECT`? Should I create a `FUNCTION`? Not sure how to do that in `.net`.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Should have mentioned that the client could also potentially send me the ID 13826, which is for Bob Smith.Mr and I would still have to get Bob Smith ID 12345 out of this, so I think I would definitely have to strip titles etc...**

Comment: do you know the correct form of bob smith? if yes, a search by that is  the easiest approach. If not, and you don't have the certain no-title bob smith, then you will need to use substring_index to find and truncate the titles. YOu could alternatively split the string at every dot and select the one with the highest length

Comment: @AdrianBR No I do not. That's the tricky part.

Comment: added an answer. THere's no fast way to working with strings here, i suggest you process step by step. WHen you create temp tables, always add the index(if needed) AFTER creation, much faster than having the index when data is inserted.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN tableName b
            ON a.companyID = b.companyID
WHERE   a.id = 12345 AND
        b.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', a.firstName, '%') AND
        b.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%', a.lastName, '%')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f3e7/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║  ID   ║ FIRSTNAME ║ LASTNAME ║ COMPANYID ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 12345 ║ Bob       ║ Smith    ║         3 ║
║ 13826 ║ Bob       ║ Smith.Mr ║         3 ║
║ 16382 ║ Dr.Bob    ║ Smith    ║         3 ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: btw, using `LIKE '%%'` doesn't use index.

Comment: I have edited my question. I forgot to mention that I might not be given ID 12345 in this case it could also be 13826, in which case I don't think the above query would work. I think I really have to strip titles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    companyID
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    companyID = (SELECT companyID FROM my_table WHERE id = 12345)
    AND firstname LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT firstname FROM my_table WHERE id = 12345),'%')
    AND lastname LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT lastname FROM my_table WHERE id = 12345),'%')
```

Or the fastest way:

```
 SELECT
        id,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        companyID
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        companyID = @companyID
        AND firstname LIKE '%@firstname%'
        AND lastname LIKE '%@lastname%'
```

Where @companyID,@firstname,@lastname are the values of this query:

```
SELECT companyID,firstname,lastname FROM my_table WHERE id = 12345
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, would this be slow? Or no slower than an INNER JOIN?

Comment: @PaulG it depends ... the join id done on `companyID` and even if it has an index it will scan some rows.. on the other part on my query for each row i make the same query 3 times ... so the best solution would be to get the company and names and then replace them in a query

Answer (score 0):

You need to *normalise* your data.

first, apply

> `lower(name)`

to convert all to lowercase

second normal step would be removing the MR. and stuff. you do this with `REPLACE(name, "mr.", "")`

if you have other junk don't forget substring_index exists
`substring_index(name, 'Mr.', -1)` will return the part of the string to the right of Mr.

After that is done, just do what the others are saying, minus the regex

```
    select * 
from table as t1 
inner join table as t2 
on t1.firstname=t2.firstname 
and t1.lastname=t2.lastname 
and t1.companz=t2.companz 
where t2.user_id=12345
```

to start you off, you are looking for

```
create table step1
select id, lower(name) as name,... from user;
create table step2
select id, replace(name, "mr.", "")... from step1;
```